# No shape is known for just created foreach nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, foreach

This can be similarly formulated to [Why are just-created TikZ shapes "unknown"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58432/why-are-just-created-tikz-shapes-unknown); but its slightly different. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[%
12pt,
journal,
onecolumn,
twoside,
draftcls,
letterpaper,
]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\singlespacing
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1.0\textwidth}% fbox,
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{bb} = [draw,line width=1pt]
\tikzstyle{brdec} = [thick, decoration={ brace, mirror, amplitude=8pt, raise=8pt }, decorate]%
\tikzstyle{brdecn} = [pos=0.5,anchor=north,yshift=-1.5em]%

\foreach \a/\b in {
  0/t1,
  1/t2,
  2/t3,
  3/t4,
  4/t5,
  5/t6,
  6/t7,
  7/t8
} {
  \typeout{1st loop; name is: bn\a};
  \node[bb] (bn\a) at (\a,0) {\b};
};

\foreach \a/\b/\c in {
  0/x1/0,
  2/x2/1,
  4/x3/2,
  6/x4/3
} {
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\next}{\a+1} % returns int
  \typeout{2nd loop; name is: brz\c};
  \draw[brdec] (bn\a.south west) -- (bn\next.south east)
    node[brdecn] (brz\c) {\b};
};

\foreach \a/\b/\c in {
  0/0/z1,
  2/1/z2
} {
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\next}{\a+1} % returns int
  \typeout{3rd loop; name is: brf\b};
  \draw[brdec] (brz\a.south west) -- (brz\next.south east)
    node[brdecn] (brf\b) {\c};
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

The output from `pdflatex` is this:

```
...ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
1st loop; name is: bn0
1st loop; name is: bn1
1st loop; name is: bn2
1st loop; name is: bn3
1st loop; name is: bn4
1st loop; name is: bn5
1st loop; name is: bn6
1st loop; name is: bn7
2nd loop; name is: brz0
2nd loop; name is: brz1
2nd loop; name is: brz2
2nd loop; name is: brz3 
3rd loop; name is: brf0
3rd loop; name is: brf1

! Package pgf Error: No shape named brz3 is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.63 }
      ;
```

Note that `brz3` should be, in fact, created (and the typeout shows that the problem is not floating point numbers, like in the solution for the question cited above) - and there are no problems referencing other nodes; in fact, if I instruct `pdflatex` to keep going after this error, I get this:

[image: test31.png]

Does anyone have an idea what is going on, and how to solve this problem?

---

EDIT: Many thanks to @alexwlchan, however, if I add commas after the first two loops (`7/t8,` and `6/x4/3,`), I get this:

[image: test32.png]

Adding a comma to the third loop (`2/1/z2,`) adds an additional rotated brace. I think with an additional comma, `tikz` runs one more iteration of the loop, but with empty arguments, thereby resulting with the extra erroneous brace. Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem comes at the end of the list of cases in your `\foreach` loops

```
\foreach \a/\b/\c in {
  0/x1/0,
  2/x2/1,
  4/x3/2,
  6/x4/3
}
```

When it reads `6/x4/3`, there’s no comma or closing brace afterwards, so it includes the whitespace in the definition of `\c`.

This means you get a node called `brz3 (+ some other stuff)`. Somebody who understands TikZ better than me could tell you exactly what that is, but it isn’t important.

This means that when TikZ looks for a node called `brz3`, it doesn’t match the one you’ve created. <s>You should add a trailing comma at the end of the list, and then it only reads the single character `3`.</s>

As sdaau has pointed out, this creates an empty entry in the loop and messes up the braces. Instead, you should bring the closing brace up, so that the entry for `3` is only a single character, and it finishes off the loop.

This matches the rest of your nodes, and the names match:

```
\foreach \a/\b/\c in {
  0/x1/0,
  2/x2/1,
  4/x3/2,
  6/x4/3}
{
  % some code here
}
```

You also need to <s>add a trailing comma</s> move the closing brace on the first loop which sets up your `bn` nodes, or you get a similar error, for the same reason.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, @alexwlchan - the compilation now passes, but the output is wrong; please see edit to OP. Cheers!

Comment: @sdaau: Try moving the final brace to remove the newline, rather than adding a trailing comma. I’ve edited to clarify.

Comment: Many thanks for that, @alexwlchan - it works! Also just adding a comment at the end, e.g. `7/t8%` worked for me (and then I can keep the end brace on its own line, too). Many thanks again - cheers!

Comment: Or you can remove the spurrious space by appending a `%` to the last line.